Deluxetable getting pushed to end of document
I'm using the AASTeX v6.3.1 class file to create a deluxetable, but it keeps getting pushed to the very end of the document, leaving a large gap between the end of the section in which it was placed and the beginning of the table. If a second section follows the table, that section will appear before the table, which still lies at the end of the document. I'm using Overleaf to render to pdf. A MWE is as follows:
\documentclass{aastex631}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Text.
\begin{deluxetable}{llll}
\tablewidth{0.95\textwidth}
\tablehead{\colhead{Column 1} & \colhead{Column 2} & \colhead{Column 3} & \colhead{Column 4}}
\startdata
A & B & C & D \\
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}
\section{Section 2}
Text.
\end{document}


You want to specify the positining parameters.
\documentclass{aastex631}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{deluxetable}{llll}[htp]
\tablewidth{0.95\textwidth}
\tablehead{\colhead{Column 1} & \colhead{Column 2} & \colhead{Column 3} & \colhead{Column 4}}
\startdata
A & B & C & D \\
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum

\end{document}


Of course, calling these “de luxe” tables is an oxymoron.

That worked, thank you. I was used to an older version of AASTeX where deluxetable didn't accept positioning parameters.
